# Why does Ctrl + V not paste in Bash (Linux shell)?

Tags: linux, bash, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste, clipboard

When I copy something to the clipboard and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd> in Bash, nothing happens; However, right clicking and selecting *Paste* does the job.

Why? Is there any reasonable issue (I'm sure there is) behind this behavior in Linux?

Comment: `Shift`-`Insert` also works

Comment: I prefer `Ctrl-Shift-V`, personally.

Comment: You can also use **Shift + Insert** in most shell environments.

Comment: In bash itself, I prefer selecting desired text and then pressing middle click. From outside, I prefer CTRL-C then Shift-Insert in bash.

Comment: What if you won't have an Insert key?

Comment: @BenRacicot, `Ctrl-Shift-V` also works.

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-V is not pasting in my clipboard, that's why I asked.

Comment: it doesn't work in windows' command prompt too

Comment: Windows has an option to allow Ctrl for copy and paste. I've noticed that Powershell seems to allow it it, at least in some modes that I've tried.

Comment: funny note: http://superuser.com/questions/675619/why-doesnt-windows-command-prompt-still-support-ctrl-v (essentially the same question as this, but about Win) was closed as "primiarily opinion-based"...

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: Actually in Windows 10 it finally does.

Comment: Use ^k from the start of the line to copy and ^y to paste. Similar commands for emacs.

Comment: @BenRacicot which keyboard doesn't have insert key?

Comment: JFTR, `Ctrl-Shirt-V` won't work on "older" terminal emulators such as `rxvt`. Another case in point is that `Shirt-Insert` inserts the contents of the so-called "PRIMARY" selection (the currently-active selection in another GUI application) while `Ctrl-v` most of the time expected to paste the content of the so-called "CLIPBOARD" selection buffer (what most people call "the clipboard" actually).

Comment: Pressing the 3rd mouse button (in my case, pressing the mouse's roller) pastes text from the clipboard into terminal.

Answer (score 405, accepted):

In the days of physical [terminals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_terminal), session-wide clipboards did not exist, only few programs supported internal copy/paste – often under the name of "buffers" or "kill rings" – and used various different keystrokes. For example, the *bash* shell uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>K</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>U</kbd> to "kill" (cut), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to "yank" (paste); this comes from [the *emacs* editor](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillingAndYanking).

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> almost everywhere in Unix was the ["interrupt" key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C#In_command-line_environments), used to cancel the current program or operation. The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> key often meant "verbatim insert" – that is, insert the following character literally without performing any associated action. For example, a normal <kbd>Esc</kbd> switches to command mode in the *vi* editor, but <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Esc</kbd> will insert the `ESC` character into the document.

The use of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste from session-wide clipboard was introduced by Mac OS in 1983 and Microsoft Windows 3.x in 1990. (Earlier Windows versions (1.x and 2.x), as well as IBM OS/2, only supported the [IBM CUA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Common_User_Access) keys <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Ins</kbd> to copy and <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ins</kbd> to paste; these shortcuts remain supported by all Windows versions.)

When GUIs with clipboard support finally reached Unix, the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> keypresses were already in use by many terminal programs. In addition, the X graphical interface had somewhat [different mechanisms](http://www.jwz.org/doc/x-cut-and-paste.html): "selections" and "cut buffers". Even now you can select text in one program and insert it using the middle mouse button, without any explicit copy action.

In short, by the time Xterm and GNOME Terminal were written (I'm guessing you use the latter), <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> *already had* a completely different meaning for many years and could not be changed. In addition, an alternative method of copying text – the "selection" – was already present in X11, so explicit copy/paste action was probably considered not as important as it would be in Windows. This means that different keyboard shortcuts had to be selected – for example, most modern terminal programs, like GNOME Terminal, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>. (If you use Xterm, the same shortcuts can be added manually using the *XTerm*vt100*translations* Xresource. Rxvt does not have such an option.)

(Most X11 toolkits also support the CUA "copy" and "paste" keys, which do not conflict with terminal programs. Unfortunately, the implementations are rather inconsistent – <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Ins</kbd> copies to the "clipboard" in most programs (GTK, Qt4, but ignored by Xaw); however, <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ins</kbd> pastes from the "primary selection" in most GTK and Qt4 programs, but from "clipboard" in Firefox, and from the now-obsolete cut-buffers in the now-obsolete Xaw.)

---

All that said, some terminals or consoles (in particular, the Windows 10 console) *do* support these keys. As the Windows console always had a separate "mark/select" mode, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> now also has two meanings based on context – in regular mode it sends an interrupt, in select mode it copies to clipboard (just like <kbd>Enter</kbd> used to).

Meanwhile, Windows command-line tools never really *used* <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for anything, so it was bound to "paste" without disturbing much anything. Doing the same on Unix-like terminals however would be more problematic.

Comment: Hmm. In Vim, “yank” means copy rather than paste. This seems to make more sense, too. Are you sure about the meaning of this term here?

Comment: [Yes, I'm sure.](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-yanking-text-278) Bash inherits the default shortcuts from [their Emacs equivalents](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/KillingAndYanking).

Comment: @grawity: your last comment is a teenie bit misguided. Bash offers two modes of command-line editing, vim-mode and emacs-mode. It just happens that emacs-mode is the default on most installs. That does raise ambiguity in the use of the term *yank*, even for bash.

Comment: A-ha!  I _knew_ the Vimperator developers made a mistake when they switched `<C-v>` to `i` in version 3, but I couldn't quite put my finger on _why_.

Comment: Soooo - why don't these projects just change these key combo's to keep up with the times and the mass of users? I'm sure there are more users that expect the ctrl+c and ctrl+v as copy and paste. I am used to using ctrl+c to stop processes, but i'm sure id get over it quickly if it is changed.

Comment: @grawity I just upvoted this excellent answer (and over the past couple of days, other related answers by you). In your first sentence, did you mean *registers* when you wrote *buffers*? A buffer (for both Vi and Emacs), is how the file contents are referred to when loaded into memory.

Comment: I tried to use you instruction for xterm 'ctrl-shift-c' and copy and pasted what you have provided in instruction to .Xdefaults but it did not work.

Comment: @Trismegistos you have to `xrdb merge ~/.Xresources` (or ~/.Xdefaults) and open another console. There are a few select other things you might have to do, but hopefully you have gotten it working by now and perhaps this might help someone else who can't get it working.

Comment: @Colin: You still missed the distinction between clipboard and X selection. There are several selections (PRIMARY, SECONDARY, CLIPBOARD), but only one of them is usually called a "clipboard" – the CLIPBOARD selection, because that's where Ctrl-C copies to, and that's where Ctrl-V pastes from. The primary selection is not the clipboard.

Comment: @grawity Oh I see how the way I stated it is confusing. I meant clipboard (lowercase) in the sense of any kind of buffer that allows you to cut and paste text. Edited: Another modern wrinkle is the widespread use of touchpads, that makes pasting from the X cut-buffer quite a gamble (what is your three-finger-tap success rate?), so I've assigned an additional xterm hotkey for pasting from the X clipboard by changing the paste-source specifier CLIPBOARD to PRIMARY in Xresources.

Comment: Note that the mouse wheel nowadays can act as the third mouse button. If your shell supports it, by clicking it you can paste text from the clipboard, as mentioned in the answer.

Comment: @JoseFaeti Yes, from your secondary clipboard that may not have the same content like your ctrl + c clipboard, because linux has two clipboard and you can make even bigger mess. I still don't understand, why they can't adapt the new 'trend'. Other consoles fully support ctrl + c and ctrl + v this. This is both usability and user experience issue...

Answer (score 51):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> for pasting.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> with other chars is usually used by the shell for special functions.

Comment: So why Linux does not register CTRL+SHIFT for special functions instead; I think copy-paste is more typical by some users than that special functions, right?

Comment: Shells have existed way before there were graphical Terminals and GUIs with cut and paste functionality, so your argument isn't really valid. @YasserZamani

Comment: Ctrl+Shift+V is executed by the terminal emulator (assuming you're using GNOME Terminal) and not by `bash` itself. If you're ever outside a GUI environment, or if you're using another term emulator, this will probably not work. Do not think this command is portable.

Comment: @rahmu Oh, had no idea about that. Use only stock Ubuntu installs. Is there a universal command?

Comment: There probably isn't one for accessing the clipboard (only Shift+Ins for the primary selection). Even the clipboard itself is an X11 thing, not accessible from tty's. However, Ctrl+Shift+V is supported by GNOME Terminal, Xfce4 Terminal, KDE Konsole; this covers the most popular GUI environments.

Answer (score 24):

Here's your general-purpose copy paste settings with popular terminals:

**gnome-terminal (most popular on Linux)**
**Copy**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
**Paste**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>
**Note**: Select-to-copy and <kbd>middle-click</kbd> to paste also works, but it uses an alternate clipboard.

**PuTTY (most popular terminal in Windows)**
**Copy**: (select with mouse, no keyboard interaction)
**Paste**: <kbd>Right-click</kbd>  (or more reliably: <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Right-click</kbd>)
**Note**: Apps that take mouse input (like `vim` and `links`) can steal <kbd>Right-click</kbd> -- <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>Right-click</kbd> will always work in any app.

**OSX Terminal**
**Copy**: <kbd>Apple</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>
**Paste**: <kbd>Apple</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>
**Note:** Apps that take mouse control (like `vim` and `links`) may override what it means to select text, in which case copy won't work the way you expect it to. In those cases, hold down <kbd>Control</kbd> while you drag the mouse to select. Mouse interaction with apps is disabled by default in your terminal settings, so most people won't even know about this.

Comment: Isn't `cmd.exe` more popular than PuTTY on Windows? :-)

Comment: @Ben Not as an SSH terminal.

Comment: No, `cmd.exe` is not an SSH terminal. That is very true.

Comment: @Ben: It is not a terminal at all - only a shell. The default terminal in Windows is the "Windows Console" component of csrss.

Comment: @Ben but right click to paste also works on `cmd.exe` (and is the only way there, if you don't want to open menu > edit > paste) in [quick edit mode](https://www.tekrevue.com/tip/boost-productivity-quickedit-mode-windows-command-prompt/). There's no shortcut in pre-win10 command prompt

Answer (score 19):

It is a deep rooted tradition that the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key together with a letter generates ASCII control characters found by subtracting 64 from the upper case letter's ASCII value. This calculation maps <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> to 1, and so on. For instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd> is <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> is linefeed.

There is no similar tradition for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>.  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> is not expected to produce any specific character.

Terminal emulators must support tradition by transparently passing through the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> convention, letting it appear as character input to the programs being operated through that terminal window.  Terminal-based programs map control keys to commands. For example, Bash uses <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> as a command which means "take the next character literally". This allows you to embed a control character in the command line. If the terminal steals control keys for its own use, such commands become unavailable. So intercepting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> for a meta-function is out of the question (at least in a default configuration).

However, terminal emulators are free to intercept <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> which isn't expected to generate a character. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> isn't a standard; it's a Gnome Terminal thing (which may be in some other terminals).

On X-based Unix desktops the convention is that no command is needed to copy. You just select the text. And the middle button pastes that text elsewhere. You will find that it works in Xterm, Gnome Terminal and Firefox alike.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> is a Microsoft Windows convention, which is an imitation of <kbd>Apple</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd> from the Macintosh.

Comment: It is not *exactly* subtraction -- traditionally Ctrl has [cleared the 6th and 7th bits](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_key#History) of the character; because of this, Ctrl+Shift+letter works identically to Ctrl+Letter in most terminals (unless it is explicitly overriden by the terminal, as in the case of copy/paste shortcuts).

Comment: *Because the keys are essentially randomly ordered with respect to the ASCII standard, the program ROM includes several look-up tables that assist in the generation of the ASCII codes. ... Holding own the CONTROL key when another key is pressed causes another table look-up.* [VT100 series Technical Manual, 4.4.9.3, Digital].

Comment: @Linger thanks for the edit. It renders nicely, but there is no way I'm typing all these `<kbd>` tags in future posts.

Comment: `Ctrl-A` is `1`. How can I try this? My Gnome terminal does nothing when I press `Ctrl-A`.

Comment: I lied in my previous comment. In the decade since, I've assiduously marked up keyboard sequences with `<kbd>`.

Answer (score 4):

To me, the simplest way to copy paste in the shell is:

Select the code you want and then past it by clicking the <kbd>mouse-middle-key</kbd>

Comment: As long as you have a middle mouse key.

Comment: @jpierson not that I am strongly recommending this, but you can write a small script that simply uses `xdotool click 2` to emulate the third-button click for you. Then, in whatever window manager / desktop environment you are in, you can bind this script to a key - say `mod` `i` (for insert) or whatever keybindings you might have available (or whatever mod might mean - which really depends where you bind this)

Comment: Whether that works or not has nothing to do with the shell, but what kind of terminal emulator you are using.. many X based terminals allow this mouse move.

Answer (score 2):

We can use insert keyboard button to do copy and paste(In old keyboards it can be missing)

**Copy**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd>
**Paste**: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Insert</kbd>

Comment: For pasting, it's normally just `Shift`+`Insert`

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the middle button an a mouse if you are feeling lazy and select a command from either a text document, script or web or forum. once you've selected the intended command simply move to your terminal and click the middle button on the mouse. I use this method as I use puppy linux which doesnt seem to support the normal behaviour of right click and paste. it does in a file handler window, just not in a terminal window. dont know why but I'm quiet pleased I found out about the middle button method, very handy! ;-)