# Why is copy-paste in Windows command-line tools usually cumbersome?

Tags: windows, command-line, keyboard-shortcuts, copy-paste

I've used the command prompt, cygwin, mobaxterm in Windows. Although they do support copy-paste, the operation is usually not that straightforward. The selection of the text in the command prompt is weird, and copy-paste the text requires multiple clicks or key combination.

Yet, in mac os, for example, you can easily copy-paste in the terminal using the usual practice <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. I wonder why things cannot be similarly easy for Windows command-line tools. Is this caused by some technical or implementation concerns?

Comment: just a quick note: Make a shortcut for the CMD.exe , then play with the shortcuts "properties" (right click). In the "Options" tab find the "Edit Options" the 2 options "Quick Edit" and "Insert Mode" there change a few things. That is what they told me to change , way back when, it doesnt make it intuitive , but it does change things for editing and copy paste stuff.

Comment: [Why doesn't windows command prompt still support ctrl + v?](http://superuser.com/q/675619/241386), [Why does Ctrl + V not paste in Bash (Linux shell)?](http://superuser.com/q/421463/241386)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> is used to send signals to console programs, for example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> will terminate the running app. Therefore generally it can't be used for shortcuts. That's why Linux terminals often use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>key</kbd> instead.

To copy/paste quickly, in previous versions of Windows there's a "quick edit mode", which is [not enabled by default](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070913-00/?p=25143). In this mode you select the text and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to copy, no need to enter mark mode like before. Then right click on the console to paste, just like what a middle click on Linux does. Still a bit cumbersome but anyway a lot faster than doing without it

Since Windows 10 MS has introduced some big [console improvements](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2014/10/07/console-improvements-in-the-windows-10-technical-preview/#25e2FUS6YmZS4qvV.97). Now you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for copying/pasting in [Windows 10 terminal](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/25590/how-to-enable-ctrlv-for-pasting-in-the-windows-command-prompt/) when there's some text being selected, otherwise a signal will be sent to the program like before.