# Text expansion tools for linux?

Tags: linux, bash, terminal, hotkeys

I am looking for a tool that can auto-close brackets and quotes in a terminal. For example, when I type

```
echo "
```

It should automatically expand into

```
echo ""
```

and put the cursor in the middle.

This is already doable in vim and many other editors, I would like to have the same feature in a terminal also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way of doing this if you use the vi mode of readline in bash:

```
set editing-mode vi
set keymap vi-insert
"\C-b": backward-char
"(": "\C-v()\C-b"
"[": "\C-v[]\C-b"
"{": "\C-v{}\C-b"
"\"": "\C-v\"\C-v\"\C-b"
"\'": "\C-v\'\C-v\'\C-b"
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your shell is bash and you use emacs editing mode (`set -o emacs`), [this answers your question for parenthesis and double quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11661658/3342206).

To explain what is going on there, here's one that works for `{}`:

```
bind '"{" "\C-v{}\e[D"'
```

Let's take a walk through the interior of the `'`. In the first pair of `"` we have:

```
{
```

This is pretty simple, it just means to replace a left curly brace with the following stuff.

The second pair of `"` starts off with:

```
\C-v{}
```

Here we insert the open and close brace. We need both because we're replacing what was originally typed, not appending to it. The `\C-v` is a <kbd>Control-v</kbd> character, which stands for a verbatim insert ([brief history of terminal keys](https://superuser.com/a/421468/302463)). This allows us to insert the `{` without triggering this binding again. Finally, we have:

```
\e[D
```

This is just the escape code for the left arrow key, so it moves the cursor to between the braces.

Comment: This is all nice, but if I have `set editing-mode vi`, it puts me out of insert mode after autocompletion, which is quite annoying.

Comment: Fair enough, I'll add a note about this being an emacs editing mode only thing to my answer and give yours an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making five bash scripts as below:

```
# terminal_autocomplete_brackets.sh
#!/bin/bash

myw=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
if [[ \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'bash .* Konsole') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*Navigator.*Firefox') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*google-chrome') \
    ]]
then
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "[]\[Left]" >/dev/null 2>&1
else
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "["  >/dev/null 2>&1
fi



# terminal_autocomplete_curly.sh
#!/bin/bash

myw=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
if [[ \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'bash .* Konsole') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*Navigator.*Firefox') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*google-chrome') \
    ]]
then
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "{}\[Left]" >/dev/null 2>&1
else
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "{" >/dev/null 2>&1
fi



# terminal_autocomplete_parentheses.sh
#!/bin/bash

myw=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
if [[ \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'bash .* Konsole') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*Navigator.*Firefox') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*google-chrome') \
    ]]
then
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "()\[Left]" >/dev/null 2>&1
else
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "(" >/dev/null  2>&1
fi




# terminal_autocomplete_quotes.sh
#!/bin/bash

myw=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
if [[ \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'bash .* Konsole') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*Navigator.*Firefox') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*google-chrome') \
    ]]
then
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\"\"\[Left]" >/dev/null  2>&1
else
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "\"" >/dev/null  2>&1
fi



# terminal_autocomplete_squotes.sh
#!/bin/bash

myw=$(xdotool getactivewindow)
if [[ \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'bash .* Konsole') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*Navigator.*Firefox') || \
    $(xprop -id ${myw} | egrep 'WM_CLASS.*google-chrome') \
    ]]
then
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "''\[Left]" >/dev/null 2>&1
else
    xvkbd -xsendevent -text "'"  >/dev/null 2>&1
fi
```

Then you can use xbindkeys to bind "'[{( to each of these five scripts, it works quite well.