# Windows 10 build 14316: Ctrl + v doesn't work on Bash on Ubuntu on Windows

Tags: bash, windows-10, copy-paste, windows-insider, windows-subsystem-for-linux

On the new Windows 10 insider build 14316, I haven't been able to use Ctrl + V (shortcut for paste) on the new Bash on Ubunbu on Windows app. Has anybody else had this issue? Any solutions?

I have edited the app's properties to enable control shortcuts and insert. Also, I have tried Ctrl + Shift + V and Shift + Insert and neither work.

Comment: Does Ctrl+Shift+V work? That's what the shortcut is in many Linux terminals. Otherwise, I seem to remember that middle click pastes in cmd (but I don't know for sure).

Comment: Ctrl + Shift + v doesn't work either. And I don't have a middle click.

Comment: if the original bash doesn't support if, Windows 10 will also not support it. Does it work in a real Ubuntu?

Comment: I don't know, I've never used the real Ubuntu. I have Windows, and hence was thrilled when the announced that they would have Bash. It just sucks not being able to copy and paste quickly. They support it for the command prompt though, so maybe they just haven't added it for their bash shell yet, or forgot. Or it's a bug, idk.

Comment: [This question](http://superuser.com/q/421463/820) may explain why.  Remember, you are essentially running Linux, so it will behave differently than you may expect if you're only used to how Windows works.

Comment: They just suggest shift + insert or Ctrl + Shift + v. Neither of those work for me though. Have you tried it? Any of it work for you?

Comment: Does clicking the window's icon (in the upper-left) produce a menu with Edit as one of its submenus? If so, Paste might be an option there.

Comment: Yeah, that works. Is there a shortcut for that? Or a way to make a shortcut?

Comment: What's interesting is that I can't paste from edit initially upon opening the Bash app. It's grayed out and only copy is available. Only when I do Ctrl + V (which just types ^V) can I access the paste option.

Comment: There's an issue open for this problem here, it seems it will be fixed in a future release: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1471

Comment: @SergeiWallace the [feature is now part of 1809 update](https://superuser.com/a/1319874/174557)

Comment: The current best answer is down below (https://superuser.com/a/1319874/551544). This is one of the cases where SO's voting mechanism is not keeping pace.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Why don't you guys just Right Click? here is how to enable copy and paste:

1. Go to the top of the bash window, right click, go to properties
2. Check the box that says Quick edit Mode, and you are set!

   [image: Copy and Paste Enabling on Bash for Windows 10]

Good day!

-- 
Activate Quick Edit mode, then mouse left-click is select text, right DOUBLE-click is PASTE

Comment: Helpful but I would say that "QuickEdit Mode" is not a hugely transparent label for saying "allow right click paste" so not surprising it was missed.

Comment: My reason for not right clicking is simple: I don't want to move my hand to the mouse if I can avoid it. Keyboard shortcuts exist for a reason, and should be maintained across the platform (I don't really care _what_ the shortcut is for copy&paste, as long as there is one).

Comment: FWIW, for me, right SINGLE-click is paste

Comment: Right click is not ctrl+v...

Comment: enabling Ctrl key didn't solve the problem for me :(

Comment: Doesn't work for pasting in SSH password.

Comment: Doesn't work for me even though my settings were already set up as in the screenshot. Asking why don't we just right click is kind of annoying. The question was about getting the keyboard shortcut working -- you're saying why not just not use the keyboard :-[

Comment: This is not a real solution to the issue.

Comment: Why is this marked the answer when it doesn't answer the specific question about keyboard shortcut ctrl+v?

Comment: @Zoey I posted the [real solution](https://superuser.com/a/1319874/174557) that works since Win10 1809

Answer (score 11):

The main issue, I believe, is that `cmd.exe` isn't dealing well with the bash environment. By itself the new `cmd.exe` actually **does** support <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> but whilst running `bash`, it doesn't.

My workaround is to use [ConEmu](https://conemu.github.io/). It's much superior to `cmd.exe` alone and even gives you color highlighting when running `bash`. I've tested it and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> does work. As a nice plus, you get a tabbed terminal.

Comment: I downloaded it. How do I configure Bash to use ConEmu instead of the normal command prompt?

Comment: ConEmu is sort of a wrapper around cmd.exe. Just by running the plain cmd.exe within ConEmu should allow you to paste by using CTRL+V.

Comment: @spwallace if you've installed bash before ConEmu, the first time you start ConEmu (which I am doing right at this very moment) the fast configuration offers to "Choose your startup task or even a shell with arguments" and bash is there. But also once you started ConEmu, the green plus menu besides the search bar also offers all sorts of shells.

Comment: ConEmu solved the Ubuntu Bash "Ctrl + V" problem for and a nice thing is that ConEmu is Open Source Software (BSD license). Plus it fixes the awful "directory path blue" that is just unreadable on black background.

Comment: Thank you. I've installed ConEmu and it's looking great so far.

Answer (score 6):

[Starting with at least Windows 10 Insider build 17643](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/commandline/2018/04/13/copy-and-paste-arrives-for-linuxwsl-consoles/), you can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>/<kbd>V</kbd> as Copy/Paste if you enable it in the bash options:

[image]

This feature is part of the October 2018 Update (1809 - Build 17763).

Comment: any update on when this is coming to public?

Comment: @FelixBöhme Felix, this is part of 1809 October 2018 Update Build 17763

Comment: It is public now.

Comment: @dreua I already posted that it is part of the 1809 update

Answer (score 5):

As far as I know there's no 'good' solution out there (quickedit paste doesn't seem to work).What I would suggest is this: create an autohotkey script:

```
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
#IfWinActive, bash
^v::
SendInput {Raw}%clipboard%
return
```

Comment: I have ConEmu running but I do not want to use Ctrl + V because that's used by `nano` so I used `+^v::`. Also, since ConEmu doesn't always have bash in the window, I used `#IfWinActive ahk_exe ConEmu64.exe`

Answer (score 3):

As we figured out in the comments, the Paste entry in the window's system menu only activates after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> once, which is unusual. After that, though, you can use the sequence <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>. (Courtesy of [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/131969/2825369) by Nescio.) That's not optimal, but it works.

If the Bash on Ubuntu on Windows window has a Properties entry in that menu, you *might* be able to check the "QuickEdit Mode" box on the Options tab to allow right-clicking in the window to count as a paste.

Comment: weird... Alt+Space doesn't bring up the menu like it should either.

Comment: @Michael same here; this bash in windows thing is pretty anemic

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not specific to "BASH on Ubuntu".  All Windows commandline windows experience this including cmd and powershell.  Access the window menu under the icon in the top left (another answer mentioned alt+space, this opens the window menu).  Choose defaults.  Enable QuickEdit mode.

By default, in QuickEdit mode, highlighting copies and right click pastes.  (Before Win 10, it still doesn't get you ctrl+c and ctrl+v).