# Use Powershell in WSL

Tags: powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I have Powershell Core 6 installed on my Windows 10, and I'm using WSL (Windows Subsystem for Linux) with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I like the Powershell 6 terminal, it supports a lot of the keyboard shortcuts you'd expect in a text editor, things like `ctrl-backspace` for deleting whole words and stuff like that; it even supports `ctrl-home` and `ctrl-end` for deleting til beginning and deleting til end respectively. The WSL terminal however, is dire in comparison. It doesn't even support `ctrl-v` for paste!!! I have to use right mouse click every time.

I know how to install Powershell on Linux, but even so, I still have to use Powershell under that terminal. Is there a way to use the normal Powershell (under Windows), but for my Ubuntu 18.04 in WSL?

Comment: `bash` shell also has many keyboard shortcuts, see [this article](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html).

Comment: @Biswapriyo I don't want to use Bash. I want to use Powershell in WSL.

Comment: @Biswapriyo You've edited some uses of the word "terminal" out of my question. I think the word "terminal" is important. I'm making a distinction between the shell itself (be it Bash or Powershell), and the *terminal* that hosts the shell.

Comment: I removed the "terminal" where it is used beside of Powershell because Powershell and WSL **itself** is not a terminal. But I remain the last "temrinal" because WSL runs terminal **inside** of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question that got bumped today with another answer (that's on track).

##### Short Answer

The biggest misunderstanding with the question itself is (as @Biswapriyo pointed out in edits and comments) is the confusion between *shell* and *terminal*.

No, you can't run "WSL" in a "PowerShell terminal" because there's no such thing as a "PowerShell terminal" (see below).

Some *shell* equivalents to the hotkeys, at least:

| Feature | PowerShell | Bash/Zsh |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Delete Previous Token | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> |
| Delete to beginning of line | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd> | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> |
| Delete to end of line | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd> | <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> |

##### Explanation

When you run WSL, you are running a *shell*.  This is `bash` by default, but could be `zsh`, or `fish`, or any of a myriad of others.

PowerShell is also a *shell*.

These shells run in a *terminal*, which is the window that presents the shell to you.  By default in Windows 10, *all* shells run in the legacy "Windows Console" by default.  This appears to be what you are running (at least at the time you asked the question).

Other terminals could include the PowerShell ISE (pretty much replaced in favor of Visual Studio Code, in my understanding), or [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal) (installable from the Windows Store).   There are quite a few others as well.  When you install a different terminal, PowerShell (as a *shell*) can run in that terminal, as can your WSL shell, as can the CMD shell.

Side note:  Windows Terminal is designed to be the replacement for Windows Console, and eventually (in Windows 11) should be able to be set as the default console.

When you press a key or key-chord (e.g. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>), that key goes through:

- Windows, which first checks to see if there are any handlers for it (e.g. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> to send the "Exit" command to an app.  Or if you have something like AutoHotkey installed, the key you press could get handled *there* first.
- Then Windows passes it to the *terminal*.  The terminal may choose to handle it.

  For example, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> is handled by the Windows Console, regardless of whether your shell is CMD, PowerShell, Bash in WSL, or anything else.  When that hotkey is pressed, the terminal will toggle between a normal Windows and Fullscreen-mode.

  There are actually *very* few keystrokes that Windows Console itself handles.  Most go on to the next step.  However, if you select the application menu (click on the icon in the upper left) and go to Properties, you can enable  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> for copy/paste.

  Windows Terminal is quite different, and handles many more keys by default.  Furthermore, you can configure almost all of them.  For instance, by default, a newly installed Windows Terminal *does* bind <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste.

  But <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> have nothing to do with the *terminal*.  This is what @Biswapriyo was trying to help you understand in the edits and comments.
- If it's not handled by Windows or the terminal, the keypress finally gets to the shell itself.

  Since Windows Console does not handle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, the *shell* receives it.  CMD and PowerShell are Windows applications, and can talk to the Windows clipboard directly, so they can trap the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, retrieve the text from the clipboard, and insert it onto the command-line.

  On the other hand, `bash` is a Linux application running under the Linux kernel.  It doesn't know how to talk to the Windows clipboard.  That's why it relies on the terminal for this.

  Further, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> has a well-established meaning in most Linux shells, and that usage predates (I believe) even the Windows usage.  See [this question](https://superuser.com/q/421463/1210833) and the first answer there for details.

  For the other editing keys, as @YorSubs pointed out in that answer, there are equivalents.  And if something isn't bound by default in your shell of choice, it's almost always configurable.

Answer (score 2):

The hotkey you reference are not unique to the PowerShell v6+ terminal. You've been able to do this since PowerShell has been around. Heck even cmd.exe has these keyboard hotkeys for years now.

Have you looked at/considered using/tried the new '[Windows Terminal](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/introducing-windows-terminal)'  for your use case?

The point folks are delivering here is that WSL exists to address Linux interactive cmd line use case specifically, not really PowerShell specific stuff. If MS does not provide a way to do what you are after, then you need to look to 3rdP.

Windows Terminal settings file - configure to what you'd like, in accordance with the docs.

```
// To view the default settings, hold "alt" while clicking on the "Settings" button.
// For documentation on these settings, see: https://aka.ms/terminal-documentation

{
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",

    "defaultProfile": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",

    "profiles":
    [
        {
            // Make changes here to the powershell.exe profile
            "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
            "name": "Windows PowerShell",
            "commandline": "powershell.exe",
            "hidden": false
        },
        {
            // Make changes here to the cmd.exe profile
            "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
            "name": "cmd",
            "commandline": "cmd.exe",
            "hidden": false
        },
        {
            "guid": "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Azure Cloud Shell",
            "source": "Windows.Terminal.Azure"
        }
    ],

    // Add custom color schemes to this array
    "schemes": [],

    // Add any keybinding overrides to this array.
    // To unbind a default keybinding, set the command to "unbound"
    "keybindings": []
}
```

See:
[Style your Windows terminal and use WSL and PowerShell like a pro](https://medium.com/@hjgraca/style-your-windows-terminal-and-wsl2-like-a-pro-9a2e1ad4c9d0)
This blog specifically talks to Ubuntu config with it.

See also, Micorosft's other free editor -

> [Developing in WSL](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl) The Visual Studio Code Remote - WSL extension
>   lets you use the Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL) as your full-time
>   development environment right from VS Code. You can develop in a
>   Linux-based environment, use Linux-specific toolchains and utilities,
>   and run and debug your Linux-based applications all from the comfort
>   of Windows.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to use PowerShell and integrate the Linux commands
into Windows as if they were native applications.

The procedure is not simple, and is documented in the Microsoft blog
[Integrate Linux Commands into Windows with PowerShell and the Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/integrate-linux-commands-into-windows-with-powershell-and-the-windows-subsystem-for-linux/).

The complete source code described in the article as well as additional help
for incorporating it into your workflow is available at
https://github.com/mikebattista/PowerShell-WSL-Interop.

Comment: Thank you for answering but your answer seems irrelevant. I haven't read all of the content in your link, but I don't care about the Linux commands. I want to use Powershell under WSL, but I don't like the WSL terminal. I want to be able to use the normal Powershell terminal, but be in WSL.

Comment: That's the way that Microsoft has provided for combining the two environments. I don't know of another way. The two environments are vastly dissimilar, so even this is remarkable.

Answer (score -1):

The standard WSL consoles all support `Ctrl-Shift-c` (copy) and `Ctrl-Shift-v` to paste (not enabled by default, go into Properties and check the option to enable this, and note that this also works in PowerShell and CMD prompts). You can also copy text by selecting it then right-clicking with the mouse). In addition, you can use `Ctrl-Shift-Enter` to toggle full screen mode, and you also have all of the power of `bash` within a bash console, so for example:

```
Tab    Autocomplete commands
Ctrl + r   Search the history of commands used
Ctrl + a / e  Move to start / end of current line
Alt + f / b   Move to the next / previous word
Ctrl + u / k  Cut all text on the left / right side of the cursor
Ctrl + w   Cut the word on the left side of the cursor
Ctrl + d   Logout of Terminal or ssh (or tmux) session,   Ctrl + l   Clear Terminal
```

Note `Ctrl u / k`. Also note `Alt-Left/Right` (with cursor keys) to jump between words.

It can also be nice to learn some `tmux` with it's great pane manipulation tools:

```
C-b : (to enter command mode), then  :ls, :help, :set mouse on  (or other commands)
C-d  (Note: no C-b first!)  (Detach from a session, or C-b d or C-b D for interactive)
'M-' stands for 'Meta' key and is the Alt key on Linux
C-b ?  (list all key bindings)   C-z  (Suspend tmux)   C-q  (Unsuspend tmux)
tmux a (Attach last session)    tmux a -t mysession   (Attach to mysession)
tmux ls (list sessions),  tmux a (attach),   tmux a -t <name> (attach named session)
tmux  (start tmux),   tmux new -s <name>,   tmux new -s mysession -n mywindow
tmux kill-session –t <name>     (kill a session)   tmux kill-server  (kill tmux server)

***** Panes (press C-b first):
"  (Split new pane up/down)                  %  (Split new pane left/right)
z  (Toggle zoom of current pane)             x  (Kill current pane)
{ / }  (Swap current pane with previous pane / next pane)   t  (Show the time in pane)
q  (Display pane indexes)                    !  (Break current pane out of the window)
m  (Mark current pane, see :select-pane -m)  M  Clear marked pane
Up/Down/Left/Right    (Change pane in cursorkey direction, must let go of Ctrl)
C-Up/Down/Left/Right  (Resize the current pane in steps of 1 cell, must hold down Ctrl)
M-Left, M-Right  (Resize current pane in steps of 5 cells)
o  (Go to next pane in current window)       ;  (Move to the previously active pane)
C-o  (rotate panes in current window)       M-o  (Rotate panes backwards)
M-1 to M-5  (Arrange panes preset layouts: tiled, horizontal, vertical, main-hor, main-ver)

***** Windows (press C-b first):
c       (Create a new window)         ,  (Rename the current window)
0 to 9  (Select windows 0 to 9)       '  (Prompt for window index to select)
s / w   (Window preview)              .  (Prompt for an index to move the current window)
w       (Choose the current window interactively)     &  (Kill the current window)
n / p   (Change to next / previous window)      l  (Change to previously selected window)
i       (Quick window info in tray)

***** Sessions (press C-b first):
$  (Rename the current session)
( / )  (Switch 'attached' client to previous / next session)
L  Switch the attached client back to the last session.
f  Prompt to search for text in open windows.
r  Force redraw of the attached client.
s  (Select a new session for the attached client interactively)
~  Show previous messages from tmux, if any.
Page Up     Enter copy mode and scroll one page up.
Space       Arrange the current window in the next preset layout.
M-n         Move to the next window with a bell or activity marker.
M-p         Move to the previous window with a bell or activity marker.

***** Buffers (copy mode)
[  (Enter 'copy mode' to use PgUp/PgDn etc, press 'q' to leave copy mode)
]  (View history / Paste the most recent text buffer)
#  (List all paste buffers     =  (Choose a buffer to paste, from a list)
-  Delete the most recently copied buffer of text.
C-Up, C-Down
M-Up, M-Down
Key bindings may be changed with the bind-key and unbind-key commands.
```

You have vastly more options in WSL to manipulate the console than in PowerShell in fact.

Comment: Note that you do have to enable Ctrl+Shift+C and Ctrl+Shift+V in the Windows Console "Properties" dialog first.  It's not enabled by default.

Comment: Good point, I should have mentioned that, which needs to be set for each instance (i.e. if you set it for CMD, you have to also set it for PowerShell and again for Ubuntu etc, I'll update to say that).